# Two questions about ImageDataGenerator class in Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

Regarding the following code from "Deep learning with Python", I have two questions:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_dir, target_size=(150, 150) batch_size=20, class_mode='binary') 
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_dir, target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')
```

1) Why is it defined a new generator for the test data? Why not just use the `train_datagen` object twice, once for train_dir and once for validation_dir?

2) Why the definitions of the `ImageDataGenerator` constructor and `flow_from_directory` function are in such a way that `rescale` argument is passed through the constructor and some other arguments such as `target_size` are passed through the `flow_from_drictory` function? Why not just pass all of them through constructor or `flow_from_directory` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reason for having separate *generators* for training and validation is because you treat your data differently in the two cases. For example, while working with batches of images, during training you need to shuffle your images during each epoch so that your model does not over-fit to the training data. Whereas it is not required during testing or validation. Further, you may perform special *data-augmentation* techniques (like scaling, shifting, rotation) while training to boost your training data and make the model robust. You need not perform any such operation while validating your trained model. Hence to accommodate for these differences while generating your batches, it is recommended to have separate generators for your training and validation.
2. **ImageDataGenerator** is a *class* of `Image preprocessing` in Keras. It is used to generate batches of data with real-time data augmentation. `rescale` is one of it's arguments, whereas the others that you mention (like, `batch_size`, `target_size`) are not part of it's argument list. These are rather listed under the **flow_from_directory**, which is a *function* of `Image preprocessing`. This function uses **ImageDataGenerator** as the base-class. You can find more details regarding he various *functions* and their corresponding *argument lists* in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for image preprocessing.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

What is the rationale behind this choice of arguments?

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L414), you'll notice that operations such as *re-scaling*, *normalization*, *rotation*, ETC are image specific operations. Hence they are mentioned as arguments to the base class (**ImageDataGenerator**) itself. All the functions defined under it inherit those by default. Whereas, arguments such as *folder path*, *batch size*, *color mode*, *shuffling*, ETC are data loading specific arguments. Hence they need to be taken care of by the data loader (which reads images from the folder) functions, which are **flow_from_directory** and **flow**. Once the images are loaded, they undergo the operations specified as argument in the base class. Hence such a choice of argument list.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first answer is perfect. About the second one, my question is that "What is the rationale behind this choice of arguments. Why the authors of keras select rescale as the constructor's arguments, while others as the flow_from_directory arguments?"

Comment: I think `target_size` is also an image-specific attribute, like `rescale`. But, one is defined in the constructor and the other in the function.

Comment: Yes, correct! On a higher level it may seem that both `rescale` and `target_size` perform image resizing. But what you need to look at is the utility it performs. If you go through the source code (I'm not putting all the relevant lines from the source code as it will create unnecessary clutter), you'll notice that `target_size` resembles to what size the image needs to be loaded at. It is something that is performed at the loader itself. Whereas `resize` is an operation that is carried out on top of it, if provided, to perform image specific (like data-augmentation) operation.

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L361-L405) the relevant utility of `target_shape`. It is used during loading the image itself. It loads `target_size` dimensional images. Whereas `resize` is an additional parameter which gets performed(may or may not)  on top of it and gets consumed by the `standardize` function ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L788)). Function that performs all normalize operation.